# Package dependencies in emacs

Tags: emacs, package-management

I'm trying to install js2-refactor mode using `package-install` inside of emacs but I'm getting a dependency error:

```
package-compute-transaction: Need package `yasnippet-20130218', but only 0.9.0.1 is available
```

I've added melpa, elpa and marmalade but it doesn't seem to want to install. Is there a way to force the install using the availible version of yasnippit?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the old fashioned way, e.g.,

1. Clone it from Github.

or

2. Click the `Download ZIP` archive button on the Github repository and then unzip it to your load-path and follow the instructions for install.

The link to the repository is here:  https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet